# C# - How to let a file talk to a Console

Tags: c#, console

I have this very specific question as i am trying to make a some kind of "Logger" in C# using Consoles.

So, to explain it:

I have a Solution with around 4 projects in.

I am kind of emulating Pokemon, but using my own GUI etc.
So, i really wanted to make a logger but i just can't make use of my console.
I created a C# Console with the name of "PokeLogger".
Now, i have my methods.
For example, in a battle turn, i want to output some data.
Example:

```
Opponent.PickSlot(getAttack, getDamage);
Opponent.UseAttack();
[HERE I WANT TO LOG IT] PokeLogger.Console.WriteLine($"Opponent used {getAttack.Name} and dealt {getDamage.DamageOutput} Damage!");
```

So now the question is: How can i init the Console or talk to it?

i tried alot but i simply cant make it.

(PS: I have other Consoles which are bound to the projects. I really want to use my new-created console for each and every Project. 1 Logger.)

Comment: "I created a C# Console with the name of "PokeLogger"" - what do you mean by "created a C# console"? It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve]. I'd also strongly advise you to use existing logging implementations rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get input in a c# console.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your attack:");
string attack = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Your attack is: " + attack);
```

In the first line you ask the user something.

In the second line they can type an answer.

In the third line they can see what happend with their input.

I am not 100% sure that this is what you were looking for. Your question is a little vague to me.

You could also always use ToString(); to change certain things to text if that is what you are looking for.